# Python - How to call api https with tls load bytes file certfile, keyfile

Tags: python, ssl, https

In python currently i am using SSLContext of ssl library load certfile, keyfile, cafile from file path, is there any way to load it in bytes from `crypto.dump_certificate(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, keystore_pkcs12.get_certificate())`, `crypto.dump_privatekey(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, keystore_pkcs12.get_privatekey())`, `crypto.dump_certificate(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, truststore_pkcs12.get_ca_certificates()[0])`

My https connection code

```
context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS)
context.load_cert_chain(certfile=kms_credentials.get_cert_file_path(),
                                keyfile=kms_credentials.get_key_file_path())
context.load_verify_locations(cafile=kms_credentials.get_ca_file_path())

self.connection = http.client.HTTPSConnection(host=HOST, port=PORT, context=context)
```

Hope someone can help me to connect https using ssl context read bytes certfile, keyfile, cafile or use other library

Comment: Hey, it would be easier to help you if you could tell what goes wrong with your code, i.e. what error message you get or what does not work.

Comment: @JarnoLamberg: its not about an error - the OP wants to use the string/bytes instead of the file names in load_cert_chain and load_verify_locations

Comment: For `load_verify_locations` there is `cadata`  parameter which provides what you ask for. As for `load_cert_chain` - there is an open feature request about this since 2012 - see https://bugs.python.org/issue16487

Comment: thank @SteffenUllrich, I also read the issue but when I use that ssl package it doesn't change anything, it still asks for file path